# Resources in class library good thing?

Tags: c#, mvvm, resources, windows-phone

I'm building a WP8 with MVVM pattern. My solution structure is splited into 2 projects:

- X.Portable (PCL containing all business logic, models and also ViewModels)
- X.WP8 (win phone app, containing platform specific converters, behaviours, assets and also Resources)

This is all OK and good, but now I have some validation to do on my ViewModels, and I want error messages to be localized, since my Resources are in WP8 project I cant access them in my viewmodels.

I know I could create some enum for errors and then in WP8, I could have converters for displaying localized messages, but that seems a bit over-engineering.

I could also move Resources into `X.Portable` project and my problem would be solved. Somehow it's dirty having Resources in a class library, but I don't really know why.

What are my options here? What is the downside of moving resources into my Portable project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any shortcomings of having resources in a class library. Why not, if it makes sense?
The other solution I can think of is to have an IoC approach (interface in class library, implementation in WP8 project). Having IoC is always good if you need unit testing (who doesn't). Perhaps you could combine the two and place implementation (and resources of course) in class library as well.